# Preserve vertical whitespace in Vue template with Prettier

Tags: vue.js, eslint, prettier

I'm using the [eslint-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue) with my Vue project.

I have the following `.prettierrc` file:

```js
// /.prettierrc
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false
}
```

And the following `.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    '@vue/prettier',
  ],
  rules: {
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
    'vue/html-self-closing': [
      'error',
      {
        html: {
          void: 'always',
          normal: 'always',
          component: 'always',
        },
        svg: 'always',
        math: 'always',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: ['vue'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
}
```

But unfortunately, prettier thinks that

```html
<template>
  <header><a href="/" class="logo"> Home </a></header>
</template>
```

Is prettier than

```html
<template>
  <header>
    <a href="/" class="logo">
      Home
    </a>
  </header>
</template>
```

[image: Prettier being annoying]

---

How can I tell prettier to preserve my vertical whitespace in the Vue template?

Are there any rules similar to what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Your only option(workaround) is using ignore.

Ex Js files. 
`// prettier-ignore`
Ex Html files.
`<!-- prettier-ignore -->`

https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the list of rules for vue in eslint: https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/rules/
But if you disable a rule it will be applied to all your code then.

Also, it seems that you can tell Prettier to ignore a block: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#html

Besides, I would argue that this is more 'readable', but that's my point of view :)

```html
<template>
  <header>
    <a href="/" class="logo">Home</a>
  </header>
</template>
```